# Animations Back to back After Completion of one in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation

I want to do continuous animation in 3 imageviews back to back I have use the below code but it shows me animation in only first imageview.I debug Code, it will Go in method but it won't show Any animation in remaining.Below is my Code

```
-(void)imageNewsAnimation
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.35f animations:^{
        _imgNews.animationImages=arrnews;
        _imgNews.animationDuration=1;
        _imgNews.animationRepeatCount=1;
        _imgNews.image = [_imgNews.animationImages lastObject];
        [_imgNews startAnimating];

    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [_imgNews stopAnimating];
        [self imageEventAnimation];
    } ];
}

-(void)imageEventAnimation
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.35f delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState animations:^{
        _imgEvents.animationImages=arrEvents;
        _imgEvents.animationDuration=1;
        _imgEvents.animationRepeatCount=1;
        _imgEvents.image = [_imgEvents.animationImages lastObject];
        [_imgEvents startAnimating];


    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [self imageDirectoryAnimation];
    } ];

}
-(void)imageDirectoryAnimation
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.35f animations:^{
        _imgDirectory.animationImages=arrdir;
        _imgDirectory.animationDuration=1;
        _imgDirectory.animationRepeatCount=1;
        _imgDirectory.image = [_imgDirectory.animationImages lastObject];
        [_imgDirectory startAnimating];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [self imageInfoAnimation];
    } ];

}

-(void)imageInfoAnimation
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.35f animations:^{
        _imgInfo.animationImages=arrinfo;
        _imgInfo.animationDuration=1;
        _imgInfo.animationRepeatCount=1;
        _imgInfo.image = [_imgInfo.animationImages lastObject];
        [_imgInfo startAnimating];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [self imageDirectoryAnimation];
    } ];

}
```

[image: Below is the Screenshot of imageview place one after another]

Comment: I am not sure if it will work but try removing this part from your second method animation code  `delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState `

Comment: It could have to do with UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState in the -(void)imageEventAnimation method. Here is a link to someone else having animation problem with that as well,

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21495970/uiviewanimationoptionbeginfromcurrentstate-unexpected-behaviour-with-basic-anima

Comment: By removing it i also tried...But not Working @rptwsthi

Comment: That won't give me fruitful results@Ro4ch please help with other alternative.

Comment: Why are you using UIView animation blocks? You aren't performing any animations inside them, image view animations don't need to be kicked off inside these blocks. And you are setting up an infinite loop between imageInfoAnimation and imageDirectoryAnimation where each calls the other from its completion block.

Comment: Yes I am setting infinite loop....But Still only first imageview show animation rest remains static @jrturton

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since startAnimating doesn't have a completion handler, I would set up something like this:

**CycleImageView.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

typedef void (^CycleCompletion)(BOOL finished);

@interface CycleImageView : UIImageView

- (void)startAnimatingWithImages:(NSArray<UIImage *>*)images completion:(CycleCompletion)completion;

@end
```

**CycleImageView.m**

```
#import "CycleImageView.h"

@interface CycleImageView()
@property (nonatomic, copy) CycleCompletion completion;
@end

@implementation CycleImageView

- (void)startAnimatingWithImages:(NSArray<UIImage *>*)images completion:(CycleCompletion)completion {
    self.completion = completion;

    NSMutableArray *imageRefs = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < images.count; i++) {
        [imageRefs addObject:(id)images[i].CGImage];
    }

    CAKeyframeAnimation *animation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"contents"];
    animation.delegate = self;
    animation.calculationMode = kCAAnimationDiscrete;
    animation.duration = 1;
    animation.values = imageRefs;
    animation.repeatCount = 1;
    animation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
    animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
    [self.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"animation"];
}

- (void)animationDidStop:(CAAnimation *)anim finished:(BOOL)flag {
    if (self.completion != nil) {
        self.completion(flag);
        self.completion = nil;
    }
}

@end
```

**To use it:**

Make imgNews, imgEvents, imgDirectory, and imgInfo all subclasses of CycleImageView. Then, using your supplied methods and variables, the implementation would change to this:

```
- (void)imageNewsAnimation {
    [_imgNews startAnimatingWithImages:arrnews completion:^(BOOL finished) {
       if (finished) {
           [self imageEventAnimation];
       } 
    }];
}

- (void)imageEventAnimation {
    [_imgEvent startAnimatingWithImages:arrEvents completion:^(BOOL finished) {
       if (finished) {
           [self imageDirectoryAnimation];
       } 
    }];
}

- (void)imageDirectoryAnimation {
    [_imgDirectory startAnimatingWithImages:arrdir completion:^(BOOL finished) {
       if (finished) {
           [self imageInfoAnimation];
       } 
    }];
}

- (void)imageInfoAnimation {
    [_imgInfo startAnimatingWithImages:arrinfo completion:^(BOOL finished) {
       if (finished) {
           // NOTE: Are you intentionally creating this indefinite animation loop?
           [self imageDirectoryAnimation];
       } 
    }];
}
```

**Edit:**

Created a [gist](https://gist.github.com/jordancarney/a9252d4891d01e4939386b155bea7725) for CycleImageView, as well.

Comment: How to make subclass of cycleimageview pls bit ellaborate @Jordan

Comment: Looks like imgNews, imgEvents, imgDirectory, and imgInfo are properties, so you would change them to CycleImageView (from UIImageView) after adding the .h/.m files to your project. (for example, CycleImageView *imgNews)

Comment: @MobileDeveloper You can change the class of the UIImageViews in the storyboard/xib, but you should also change the class in the source files. You should be able to do this without reseting the connection.

Comment: Yes I Did it But it Got Crashed with error as "|warning| Got a keyboard will hide notification, but keyboard was not even present."  And "[UIImageView startAnimatingWithImages:completion:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x12f6c95a0"  @jordan

Comment: @MobileDeveloper notice it says UIImageView unrecognized selector; meaning, it isn't set up as a CycleImageView correctly in the storyboard/xib. Make sure the custom class is set correctly in the interface file. Screenshot of where to set it: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ji6697p930spbd1/Screen%20Shot%202016-05-04%20at%2011.55.21%20AM.png?dl=0

Comment: I did it but still same problem only first image shows animation and remaining wont. Actually in 2nd imageview When i debug I see it wont go in CycleImageviews start animating but it will go after completion @Jordan

Comment: @MobileDeveloper Are these image views on top of each other?

Comment: No its one after Another i updated d question wid screenshot it will open and close one after another @Jordan

Comment: @MobileDeveloper it sounds like you have some issues elsewhere in the code, too. I would be willing to help, but would need to see the rest of your code.

Comment: Thanx For Efforts..I tried With Different way but this Might works@Jordan

Answer (score 0):

Perform animation with timer like

In `viewDidLoad`:

```
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2 target:self selector:@selector(imageAnimation:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
i = 0;
```

then

```
- (void)imageAnimation:(UIImage *) image {
    i++;
    if (i > 2) {
        i = 0;
    }
    NSArray *arr = @[[UIImage imageNamed:@"img1"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"img2"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"img3"]];
    UIImage * toImage = [arr objectAtIndex:i];
    [UIView transitionWithView:self.view
                      duration:2
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                    animations:^{
                        self.imageview.image = toImage;
                    } completion:NULL];
}
```

Hope this help!